# Can't Retrieve dropzone node on queuecomplete?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js

I want to retrieve the node of the dropzone that has completed it's upload queue (there are multiple on the same page), but I am having difficulty

```
var dropzone = new Dropzone("#" + dz_id, {
                autoProcessQueue: true,
                url: url + endpointFileMgr,
                headers:{"APIKey":APIKey, "IndexUUID": Indexes[i].IndexUUID,"Cache-Control": "",},
                maxFilesize: 1024, //MB
                queuecomplete: function(e){
                    // alert("e innerHTML " + e.innerHTML); // No Alert, Console Error "Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined"
                    //alert("e.target.innerHTML " + e.target.innerHTML); // No Alert, Console Error "Cannot read property 'target' of undefined"
                    alert ("this.innerHTML " + this.innerHTML); // Alert's 'this.innerHTML undefined'
                    alert("$(e).html()" + $(e).html()); // Alert's '$(e).html() undefined'
                    //alert("$(this).html()" + $(this).html()); // No Alert, Console Error "Cannot read property 'createDocumentFragment' of undefined"
                    //alert ("$(dropzone).html() " + $(dropzone).html()); // No Alert, Console Error "Cannot read property 'createDocumentFragment' of undefined"
                    alert(e.currentTarget.innerHTML); // No alert, "Cannot read property 'currentTarget' of undefined"
                }
            });
```

I am creating multiple dropzones programmatically in a loop which is why I pass my options as an object instead of accessing afterwards as suggested in the Dropzone documentation.

The [Dropzone Documentation](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#configuration) suggests that all events should pass an event argument, and from my understanding I should be able to retrieve the node that recieved the event from this argument, or from 'this' ... or somewhere at all, but it seems my understanding is flawed.

Could somebody explain to me, what the correct approach to this would be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define the `queuecomplete` option like:

```
{
  // .....
  queuecomplete: function(e) {
    // ---
  }
}
```

What you are doing in this case is override dropzone's own behavior on `queuecomplete`, unless you really want to do this you should attach your own event listener to the `queuecomplete` event like this:

```
var dropzone = new Dropzone("#" + dz_id, {
  autoProcessQueue: true,
  url: url + endpointFileMgr,
  headers: {
    APIKey: APIKey,
    IndexUUID: Indexes[i].IndexUUID,
    "Cache-Control": ""
  },
  maxFilesize: 1024, //MB
  init: function() {

    let thisDropzone = this;

    this.on("queuecomplete", function() {
      alert(thisDropzone.element.innerHTML);
    });
  }
});
```